# If your app supports account creation, you must also offer account deletion within the Android app available on Play Store/Play Console?

Tags: java, android, google-play, app-store, google-play-console

If your app supports account creation, you must also offer account deletion within the app. Is it compulsory to provide account deletion option for Android Apps on Play Store/Play Console ?
I am sure that AppStore(Apple Store) makes its compulsory to provided account deletion option within the app.
I am not sure whether this applies for Google Play Console/Google Play Store.
Please suggest a link where I can clarify my doubt.

Searched for multiple google play console policies but didn't find any clue regarding this issue. Expecting a link to clarify my doubt.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions

Comment: Or to put it differently, questions here are about programming (and closely related topics), but not legal problems.

Comment: As I sow there is not requirements than your app must to provide account deletion. You only must to provide clerify description in your Privacy Policy how user can delete user data from your service. For example by request. See "The developer’s data retention and deletion policy." section from https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10144311?visit_id=638071488555400797-3932952839&rd=1&hl=en